# Command Line failing to print some print statements

Tags: java

So I have a program and in one line it is printing out a variable stored in an object. It works perfectly fine in any IDE I've tried (blue-J and Eclipse) but when I run it in cmd it just gives blank, any ideas what is wrong?

Image of code and how it runs on IDE vs. CMD
[image: Image of code and how it runs on IDE vs. CMD]

Comment: You should post full class source code.

Comment: are you running from jar file ?

Comment: No, when I run it from CMD I use a .class file

Comment: Could be that the words are empty... Try printing ```ans.isEmpty()```, just to see what happens.

Comment: I don't think so as it works perfectly fine in Eclipse but when I copy it into a txt file and run it on CMD or make it into a jar file I get the blanks shown above

Comment: Taking the input goes through the console, which is different for Eclipse and cmd, it seems worth a try to me, or at least echo back the input.

Comment: *edit* tried printing ans.isEmpty() and it's coming back as false so there is definitley something there

Answer (score 0):

ohh i think command line has small limits on words to display the and i think the first print was covered by the second print you should use println or do something like this :

```
System.out.println(ans + " with score " + smallestAccept[i].getScore());
```

Comment: No such luck, exact same output from CMD

Comment: It's working now if I put ans after .getScore(), I have absolutely no idea why but it is working :D I tried adding more words before the " with score " section and none of that printed out on cmd either, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.print(ans);
System.out.print(" with score: " + smallestAccept[i].getScore() + "\n");
```

or this :

```
System.out.println(ans);
System.out.print(" with score: " + smallestAccept[i].getScore() + "\n");
```